# Background service isn't working properly

Tags: java, android, service, locking

I'm trying to implement service in android to make an app locker.

I'm trying to check the which activity is running on the foreground and if it's locked, forwarding it to my Locker activity.

I've added the service in manifest too, but it isn't working at all. 
Here's the code `

```
    private static Timer timer = new Timer();
    public Boolean userAuth = false;
    private Context mContext;
    public String pActivity = "";

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;
        startService();
    }

    private void startService() {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 0, 500);
    }

    private class mainTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            toastHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private final Handler toastHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String activityOnTop;

            ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
            //Getting the foreground activity name
            activityOnTop=tasks.get(0).processName;
            //Checking it against the app I need to lock
            if (activityOnTop.equalsIgnoreCase("com.droiddigger.techmanik")) {
                Intent lockIntent = new Intent(mContext, Lockscreen.class);
                lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mContext.startActivity(lockIntent);
            } else if(activityOnTop.equalsIgnoreCase("com.droiddigger.applocker")){

            }else{

            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: it isn´t working at all means?.......

Comment: I don't see any effects on the app I want to lock

Answer (score 0):

You must start that service. It can be done in an Activity or a BroadcastReceiver.

`startService(new Intent(this, UpdaterServiceManager.class));`

For example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
        finish();
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

You are always retrieving the item 0 of the list called *tasks*. Looking at the SDK documentation, it is said that list order is not especified: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses()

> Returns a list of RunningAppProcessInfo records, or null if there are
>   no running processes (it will not return an empty list). **This list
>   ordering is not specified.**

You must get the current visible activity other way. I suggest an AccessibilityService

Comment: I think I'm having problem with fetching the foreground activity name 


`String activityOnTop;

                ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

                List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
                //Getting the foreground activity name
                activityOnTop=tasks.get(0).processName;`



the string activityOnTop always shows the applocker's name.